# How to append int value to string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSMutableString  *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
[selectDay stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", yearNumber];
NSLog(@"%@",selectDay);
```

I will tried this one.But it can't append the yearNumber to that String please help me.YearNumber contain 2011.

Comment: warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSMutableString *' wont you get this warning??

Comment: you have asked six questions, none accepted. Please accept the answer that solves your problem by clicking the tick mark below the downvote arrow. Otherwise you may not receive better help from this community.

Answer (score 6):

`stringByAppendingFormat:` returns the new string, it does not modify the receiver string. That's why you are getting no change. Try this:

```
NSMutableString  *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
NSString *newString = [selectDay stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", yearNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

Or this:

```
NSMutableString  *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", selectDay, yearNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

EDIT: Actually you don't need mutable string for this. `selectDay` should be a normal `NSString`.

```
NSString  *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
```

Answer (score 2):

change the below line

```
[selectDay stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", yearNumber];
```

to

```
selectDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", selectDay, yearNumber];
```

definitely it will work ...

Answer (score 1):

```
   NSString *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
    NSString *appendedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",selectDay, yearNumber];

    NSLog(@"%@",appendedString);
```

Try this

Comment: I also added a comment for "using a constant NSString to initialize a pointer to NSMutableString is plain wrong" in the question

Comment: Have deleted my previous comment after you've modified your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
NSString   *selectDay=@"Wed 14 May";
    int yearNumber=2011;
    selectDay=[selectDay stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", yearNumber]];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectDay);
```

Comment: Point is, `stringByAppendingFormat:` does not modify `selectDay`, it returns a new string (which is simply lost as it's not assigned to a variable).

Answer (score 1):

You define your variable to be of type `NSMutableString *`, but the constant string you're passing is of type `NSString *` which is already wrong. There are two solutions: with or without NSMutableString.

```
NSMutableString *selectDay = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Wed 14 May"];
[selectDay appendFormat:@"%i", yearNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", selectDay);
```

Here the mutable string is generated from the constant string and then it is modified through appending.

```
NSString *selectDay = @"Wed 14 May";
NSString *newDay = [selectDay stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", yearNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", newDay);
```

The point here is that `stringByAppendingFormat:` does not modify the original string, it returns a new one. And you simply need to "catch" it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSString *selectDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wed 14 May %d", yearNumber];
```